# Powershell: Switch statement loses object in the pipe

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with PowerShell 3.0, that does not occur in PowerShell 2.0.  When I execute this code, after importing the record into `$_`, I output the fields from the CSV file.  That's fine.  When it calls the function to do the same thing with the Switch statement before, it's no longer available in the `$_` variable.  If I remove the function and put the Switch statement inside the ForEach and then Write-Host, it outputs just fine.  Does anyone have any insight into this, and how to get around this issue?  Thanks!

```
Function print {

    Switch -regex ("m") {
        "[a-b]" { $x = "ab"; break }
        "[c-d]" { $x = "cd"; break }
        "[e-f]" { $x = "ef"; break }
        "[g-h]" { $x = "gh"; break }
        "[i-j]" { $x = "ij"; break }
        "[k-l]" { $x = "kl"; break }
        "[m-n]" { $x = "mn"; break }
        "[o-p]" { $x = "op"; break }
        "[q-r]" { $x = "qr"; break }
        "[s-t]" { $x = "st"; break }
        "[u-v]" { $x = "uv"; break }
        "[w-x]" { $x = "wx"; break }
        "[y-z]" { $x = "yz"; break }
    }

    Write-Host $_.givenname
    Write-Host $_.surname
    Write-Host $_.username

}


Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" ("D:\alphabet.csv") | `
    Foreach {

        Write-Host $_.givenname
        Write-Host $_.surname
        Write-Host $_.username

        print
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass the `$_` value directly to the `print` function?  First define the `print` function to take a parameter

```
Function print {
  param ($value)

  Switch -regex ("m") {
   ...
  }

  Write-Host $value.givenname
  Write-Host $value.surname
  Write-Host $value.username

}
```

Then pass it to the function

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" ("D:\alphabet.csv") | `
    Foreach {

        Write-Host $_.givenname
        Write-Host $_.surname
        Write-Host $_.username

        print $_
}
```

Note I'm not sure why this changed between versions.  My guess is the behavior in 2.0 was just an accident of implementation and not necessarily intended by the environment.

Comment: Thanks JaredPar for your response.  This was just an example, but yes, I could pass in the whole object.  The problem with doing this is that this is a small part to a rather large script that would require massive updates, so was hoping for a less intrusive solution.

Comment: @cluckinchicken i'm going to guess you can't avoid this.  It sounds like they made a behavior change (intended or not) and I'm guessing there isn't a way to fix this.

Comment: After reviewing my script, looks like I call the function twice so given that, I removed the problem function, inserted the code where the function was called, modified a loop so as not to have to call the function again, and replaced the switch statement with an If statement.  Yada yada yada, not ideal, but at least it works.  I'll accept your answer as a workaround.  Thanks again for your input!